# Let $A\in M_n(\Bbb{C})$, show that the followings are equivalent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

The whole question looks like-

> Let $A\in M_{n\times n} (\Bbb{C})$, show that the followings are
>   equivalent-
>  (a) $A^2=BA$ for some non-singular matrix $B$ 
> (b)
>   $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(A^2)$
>  (c) $\text{Im}(A)\cap
>  \text{Ker}(A)=\{\theta\}$, where $\text{Im}(A)=\{AX|X\in\Bbb{C^n}\}$
>   and $\text{Ker}(A)=\{X\in\Bbb{C}^n|AX=\theta$}
>  (d) There exists
>   non-singular matrices $P$ and $D$ of orders $n\times n$ and
>   $\text{rank}(A)\times\text{rank}(A)$ respectively such that $$ A=P
>  \begin{pmatrix} D & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} P^{-1} $$

I want to prove the equivalance in the following manner- (a)$\implies$(b)$\implies$(c)$\implies$(d)$\implies$(a)
(a)$\implies$(b): We know $\text{rank}(BA)=\text{rank}(A)$ for some non-singular matrix $B$, hence $\text{rank}(A^2)=\text{rank}(A)$.
(b)$\implies$(c): Let, $AX\in\text{Im}(A)\cap\text{Ker}(A)\implies A(AX)=\theta\implies A^2 X=\theta\implies X\in \text{Ker}(A^2)$
$\dim(\Bbb{C^n})=\text{nullity}(A)+\text{rank}(A)$ and $\dim(\Bbb{C^n})=\text{nullity}(A^2)+\text{rank}(A^2)$
$\implies \text{nullity}(A)=\text{nullity}(A^2)$, since $\text{Ker}(A)\subseteq \text{Ker}(A^2)$, hence $\text{Ker}(A)=\text{Ker}(A^2)$.
Thus, we get $X\in \text{Ker}(A)\implies AX=\theta\implies \text{Im}(A)\cap\text{Ker}(A)=\theta$
Now, I cannot proceed further.
How to prove (c)$\implies$(d) and (d)$\implies$(a)? Can anybody suggest me a proper proof?
Thanks for assistance in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For d implies a:

$$\begin{align}
A^2 &= P\begin{pmatrix} D^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} P^{-1} \\
&= P\begin{pmatrix} D & 0 \\ 0 & I  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} D & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} P^{-1}  \\
&=P\begin{pmatrix} D & 0 \\ 0 & I  \end{pmatrix} P^{-1} P \begin{pmatrix} D & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} P^{-1} \\
&=P\begin{pmatrix} D & 0 \\ 0 & I \end{pmatrix} P^{-1} A
\end{align}
$$
and 
$$
B = P\begin{pmatrix} D & 0 \\ 0 & I \end{pmatrix} P^{-1}
$$
is non-singular

For c implies d, I'll leave out some details for you, but the idea is to let $k=\text{rank}(A)$ and $f_n,f_{n-1},\ldots,f_{n-k}$ be a basis for $\text{Ker}(A)$.  Then we can extend this to a basis for all of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and let $P$ be the matrix that takes the standard basis to the new basis.

Comment: For (c) implies (d) where you have used the condition of (c)? And how are you sure that $P$ is non-singular?

Comment: Well, I said I'd leave out some details.  Change of basis matrices are always non-singular.  I used the condition to that the image intersects the kernel in only the $0$ vector to get that the lower left entries are all $0$.

Comment: Actually, this is probably too fast and loose.  To be clear, we have to be careful with how we complete the basis; but the point is you can complete the basis in such a way that the image is orthogonal to the kernel.